# Dataframe manipulation in R - Shift cells to the left and remove NAs

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe whose columns consists of randomly distributed values and NAs, as seen below:

```
a<-c("S","E","NA","S","NA")
b<-c("A","NA","M","G","K")
c<-c("I","NA","NA","NA","L")
meh<-dataframe(a,b,c)

#  [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#a "S"  "E"  "NA" "S"  "NA"
#b "A"  "NA" "M"  "G"  "K" 
#c "I"  "NA" "NA" "NA" "L"
```

I want to remove all NAs and shift the non-NAs to the left - it should look like this

```
#  [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#a "S"  "E"  "S"  
#b "A"  "M"  "G"  "K" 
#c "I"  "L"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Hint: `dataframe` should be `data.frame`, which will not give you the result you have. `meh <- rbind(a,b,c)` will however. Also `"NA"` is a string, which is not the same as `NA` the missing value.

Comment: something like `lapply(1:nrow(meh), function(x) meh[x,][!meh[x,] =="NA"])`? You can't have a data.frame (or matrix) with ragged ends like this.

Answer (score 1):

It might help if you specify what you want to do with the data after you finish this process, but here's a way to get rid of NA's in the each column and store them to a variable. That is if you actually have NA's. I changed your example dataset to reflect the comments above to include NA not "NA".

```
 a<-c("S","E",NA,"S",NA)
 b<-c("A",NA,"M","G","K")
 c<-c("I",NA,NA,NA,"L")
 meh<-data.frame(a,b,c)

 newcol<-na.omit(meh$a) #Removes all NA's from your column
 newcol<-newcol[1:length(newcol)] #Gives you an output without any NA's
```

The same can be done with each row like jeremycg suggests, using lapply.

```
 lapply(1:nrow(meh), function(x) meh[x,][is.na(meh[x,])==F])
```

Answer (score 1):

We can also use `stri_list2matrix`

```
library(stringi)
stri_list2matrix(lapply(meh, function(x) x[x!='NA']), fill='', byrow=TRUE)
#    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,] "S"  "E"  "S"  ""  
#[2,] "A"  "M"  "G"  "K" 
#[3,] "I"  "L"  ""   ""
```

Comment: Is this possible to accomplish by using grep or contains (or something similar) for your identifier instead of "NA"?

Comment: @Phil_T  I think the OP made a mistake by creating character string for `"NA"`.  Instead it should be `NA` without quotes and then it is easier to identify with `is.na`.  Here, the `"NA"` is an exact match, so the `!=` is only needed, if you want to use `grep` then use the `fixed = TRUE` argument as well

Answer (score 0):

Once the vectors are all different sizes, it doesn't make sense to colbind them back into wide form. Instead,

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

meh %>%
  gather(variable, value) %>%
  filter(!is.na(value))
```