# R - How to delete empty or na cells in a data frame or data table and shift cells to left

Tags: r

I'm having a data frame something like below:

```html
<table><tr><th>Col1</th><th>Col2</th><th>Col3</th><th>Col4</th><th>Col5</th></tr><tr><td>1a<br></td><td>1b</td><td>1c</td><td>1d</td><td>1e</td></tr><tr><td>2a</td><td><br></td><td><br></td><td>2d</td><td>2e</td></tr><tr><td>3a</td><td><br></td><td><br></td><td>3d</td><td>3e</td></tr><tr><td>4a</td><td>4b</td><td>4c</td><td>4d</td><td>4e</td></tr></table>
```

trying to delete empty cells and repalce them with cells to right.

In R i'm trying to achieve 'shift cells to left' functionality after deleting specific cells as in excel.

Expected Output:

```html
<table><tr><th>Col1</th><th>Col2</th><th>Col3</th><th>Col4</th><th>Col5</th></tr><tr><td>1a<br></td><td>1b</td><td>1c</td><td>1d</td><td>1e</td></tr><tr><td>2a</td><td>2d</td><td>2e</td><td><br></td><td><br></td></tr><tr><td>3a</td><td>3d</td><td>3e</td><td><br></td><td><br></td></tr><tr><td>4a</td><td>4b</td><td>4c</td><td>4d</td><td>4e</td></tr></table>
```

Comment: By empty you mean `NA`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33883421/dataframe-manipulation-in-r-shift-cells-to-the-left-and-remove-nas checkthe link

Comment: PoGibas: empty mean blank "".

Comment: Wen: thanks for posting link, it had helped me in understanding, though not a full solution to my pbm.